Testing if a value is in an array with a wildcard
I have this value: $ArrVar_ASP=@("Adobe*","UXP WebView Support")
$($pre.DisplayName) --> Adobe Acrobat (64-bit)
If ($($pre.DisplayName) -notin $ArrVar_ASP) {$ArrVar_ASPPreinstalltemp+=$pre} 
But it does not recognise Adobe Acrobat (64-bit) as a member --> Adobe*
Then this value should not be add to the Array $ArrVar_ASPPreinstalltemp
How may I do that?
Thanks,
Finding if a value is member of an array and the array is containing a wildcard. If the value is existing then not adding it to another array.

Francois, -in -notin -contains -notcontains do not support wildcards or regex. They only find full matches. The same is true for the .Contains method.

Two asides: You don't need $(...) around $pre.DisplayName, and "growing" arrays with += is ill-advised for performance reasons - see this answer


As of PowerShell 7.4.x, there is no direct way to match a string against an array of patterns as opposed to literal strings - neither with -match (which operates on regex patterns), nor with -like (which operates on wildcard patterns).

GitHub issue #2132 is a proposal to introduce such support for -like (and its negated form, -notlike), but the discussion around it has stalled.

By contrast, -in and -contains (and their negated counterparts, -notin and -contains) test a value against an array's elements literally, in full, i.e. they perform element-by-element -eq comparisons.

For now, a concise workaround is to use the intrinsic .Where() array method with a per-element -like operation, and rely on PowerShell's implicit to-Boolean coercion to infer whether or not an element pattern matched:
# The string to test against the wildcard patterns.
$val = 'Adobe Acrobat (64-bit)' # your $pre.DisplayName value

# Use the .Where() method to find the first matching pattern.
# If there is one, the `if` conditional evaluates to `$true`, otherwise to $false.
if (@('Adobe*', 'UXP WebView Support').Where({ $val -like $_ }, 'First')) {
  'found'
  # ...
}

Note: The 'First' argument isn't strictly necessary, but improves performance, as it stops filtering once a match has been found.

If you're willing to work with regexes instead, you can make do with  a single one, using |, the alternation symbol, to separate the patterns, which then enables a -match solution.
However, this not only requires translating wildcard syntax into regex syntax, but also selective anchoring of the patterns, to ensure that a given pattern matches in full or only as a prefix, and not just as a substring anywhere in the input string, because -match - unlike -like - matches substrings rather than whole values by default:
# The string to test against the regex.
$val = 'Adobe Acrobat (64-bit)' # your $pre.DisplayName value

# Test against the alternation-based regex, i.e. multiple patterns
# separated by "|". "^" matches the start of the input string, "$" the end.
if ($val -match '^Adobe|^UXP WebView Support$') {
  'found'
  # ...
}

If you have an array of patterns that you want to programmatically transform into a single, alternation-based regex, use the technique shown in this answer.

Nice to make up your own language.  Close as I can come is this.  += kills puppies.  Matching against an array of wildcard patterns is a common question.
$ArrVar_ASP = 'Adobe*', 'UXP WebView Support'
$pre = [pscustomobject]@{DisplayName='Adobe Acrobat (64-bit)'}

$ArrVar_ASP | foreach-object { $pre.DisplayName -like $_ }
True
False

if ($true -in ($ArrVar_ASP | % { $pre.DisplayName -like $_ })) {
  $ArrVar_ASPPreinstalltemp += $pre
} 

Or with the regex "or" symbol:
'Adobe Acrobat (64-bit)' -match 'Adobe|UXP WebView Support'
True

